# Not able to suspend or hibernate

Tags: 10.10, suspend, hibernate

My Ubuntu 10.10 on my laptop Lenovo T400 is not able to suspend or hibernate.

Whenever I click Suspend or Hibernate,

- the moon LED on the bottom of the lid
  flashes a few seconds, the screen
  quickly shows something like "some
  devices fail to suspend, error 5",
- and then the moon LED goes off and
  the display still has ambient light
  illumination. I suppose in suspend or
  hibernation state, the display should
  have no illumination, just like when
  the laptop is turned off, right?
- If I press any key, the unlock screen
  dialogue will pop out.

I searched a little on the internet, and installed 'acpi-support' according to some advice but it does not help. Any suggestions to solve this problem? Thanks and regards!

---

ADDED:

Laptop specifications:

```
CPU
    Intel Mobile Core 2 Duo P8800  @ 2.66GHz
    Penryn 45nm Technology
RAM
    1.9GB Single-Channel DDR3 @ 532MHz (7-7-7-20)
Motherboard
    LENOVO 2764CTO (None)
Graphics
    ThinkPad Display 1440x900 @ 1440x900
    ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3400 Series (Lenovo)
Hard Drives
    244GB Western Digital WDC WD2500BEVS-08VAT2 (SATA)
Optical Drives
    HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GSA-U20N
    AZCDW EFCPUZ452 SCSI CdRom Device
    AZCDW EFCPUZ452 SCSI CdRom Device
Audio
    Conexant 20561 SmartAudio HD
```

Comment: how large is your swap partition?

Comment: @starcom: 4 GB.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I have confirmed this on my T400 now. It seems to be problem with the latest kernel. So if you are not using kernel 2.6.35-24, do that and it will probably solve your problem also.

Comment: Thanks! Kernel 2.6.35 cannot suspend nor hibernate; Kernel 2.6.32 can suspend but cannot hibernate (it shows a screen of successfully writing the content of RAM to file when clicking Hibernate, but when I try to wake it up by pressing startup key on the keyboard, it restarts instead of waking up).

Comment: @tim: For me it also looks like it does a restart when waking up from hiberate, but it is actually not. Doesn't it go to screensaver after the boot up?

Comment: It is like a restart, because I am to choose which kernel and OS to boot into asked by GRUB, and my previous open windows are all gone. It is not completely like a restart, as there is no Ubuntu startup sound.

Answer (score 2):

Excerpt from [SOURCE:](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10244071&postcount=6)

*Found this solution for my Dell Mini 1012. Thank God it works:*

> Originally Posted by Petri K
>
> Hi!
>
> This problem affects not just the Lenovo T400 but also for example the
>   new Dell Latitude E4200, HP EliteBook 2530p, Sony Vaio VGN-TT1,
>   Toshiba R600, or anything else with the "Mobile Intel® GM45 Express
>   Chipset" or X4500. I have exactly the same symptoms on my E4200
>   running intrepid.
>
> The bug most certainly resides in the xserver-xorg-video-intel code.
>   The fact that is manifests itself only with gnome desktop and not with
>   KDE or text mode gives some clue. It is not compiz related as
>   disabling compiz has no effect. I would say that this is a classical
>   multiprocessor concurrency control problem! Disabling all but one core
>   makes the bug disappear.
>
> Here is my suggestion for a workaround. Save in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/00CPU`
>   with `755` permissions. Note that it has to be called 00CPU so that it
>   gets executed before and after anything else.
>
> Code:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> # Workaround for concurrency bug in xserver-xorg-video-intel 2:2.4.1-1ubuntu10.
> # Save this as /etc/pm/sleep.d/00CPU
>
> . "${PM_FUNCTIONS}"
>
> case "$1" in
>   hibernate|suspend)
>       for i in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/online ; do
>           echo 0 >$i
>       done
>       ;;
>   thaw|resume) 
>       sleep 10    # run with one core for 10 secs
>       for i in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/online ; do
>           echo 1 >$i
>       done
>       ;;
>   *)
>       ;;
> esac
> ```
>
> Please report if this works for you! The sleep period can easily be
>   made longer if necessary.
>
> Petri K

Answer (score 1):

What graphics adapter do you have? The proprietary drivers for nVidia and ATI sometimes do not play well with ACPI suspend mode.

Comment: see my update. Looks like ATI.

Comment: I got the same problem. It worked before, but I don't know if it is because of when I updated to the latest kernel it stopped working